# html input value is not getting fetched in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple code to fetch a value from text field and so its summation and display it in the third text field

Correct code

```
var a = document.getElementById("fNo");
var b = document.getElementById("sNo");
var c = document.getElementById("tNo");
var d = document.getElementById("abc");
d.addEventListener("click", function() {
  c.value = Number(a.value) + Number(b.value);
});
```

But when I obtain value in a like this

```
a = document.getElementById("fNo").value;
```

It doesnt work.

Comment: It doesn't work because `document.getElementById("fNo")` is empty when you call its `value` property.

Comment: I dnt understand why, in w3 schools it is wriyyen in same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get a string querying the value. 
If the input element is of type "number" you can use:

```
a = document.getElementById('fNo').valueAsNumber;
```

otherwise you have to convert the string to a number, before you can do the calculation:

```
a = Number(document.getElementById('fNo').value);
b = // etc.
```

Comment: that i know type casting but why a = document.getElementById("fNo").value; this is not working